# Fill values based on reference table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, data-science

I have two df with different lenghts, one (reference/dictionary) with various types of products and brand who makes them, and another df with just the products, I have to fill brand based on the reference table

Reference df is like

| Product | Brand |
| --- | --- |
| Shirt | Zara |
| Sneakers | Nike |
| Pants | Zara |
| Tennis ball | Wilson |
| Football ball | Adidas |
| Football boots | Adidas |

The df to be filled is something like

| Product | Brand |
| --- | --- |
| Shirt | NaN |
| Shirt | NaN |
| Pants | NaN |
| Tennis ball | NaN |
| Shirt | NaN |
| Football boots | NaN |
| Football boots | NaN |
| Football boots | NaN |
| Pants | NaN |
| Sneakers | NaN |
| Football ball | NaN |
| Football boots | NaN |
| (+100k rows) | NaN |

I´ve tried the following code

```
df['Brand'] = df['Brand'].map(referencedf.set_index('Product')['Brand'])
df
```

Unfortunately, the output is not the desired and it always returns the same brand for all products

| Product | Brand |
| --- | --- |
| Shirt | Zara |
| Shirt | Zara |
| Pants | Zara |
| Tennis ball | Zara |
| Shirt | Zara |
| Football boots | Zara |
| Football boots | Zara |
| Football boots | Zara |
| Pants | Zara |
| Sneakers | Zara |
| Football ball | Zara |
| Football boots | Zara |
| (+100k rows) | Zara |

Any ideas on how can i get the output right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df['Brand'] = df['Product'].map(reference_df.set_index('Product')['Brand'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           Product   Brand
0            Shirt    Zara
1            Shirt    Zara
2            Pants    Zara
3      Tennis ball  Wilson
4            Shirt    Zara
5   Football boots  Adidas
6   Football boots  Adidas
7   Football boots  Adidas
8            Pants    Zara
9         Sneakers    Nike
10   Football ball  Adidas
11  Football boots  Adidas
```